# difference in pre and post populations

Tags: stata, group-differences

I'm looking at the difference in demographics of people with a disease pre-outbreak and post-outbreak (e.g. age, sex, location etc).

I know how to use $t$ tests and $\chi^{2}$-tests for comparison (e.g. difference of means for age), and I'm getting ridiculous statistical significance, but what I would like to know is the difference at the individual group level, i.e. at a state level, was there a difference pre/post outbreak?

I have a column with "state" and a column with "outbreak", so how could I perform that analysis? I'm using Stata 13 (as per the wishes of my supervisors). If this question has already been answered could you please direct me there?

**Edit**

I have the seven Australian states (e.g. WA, NSW etc.) and I would like to know if there was a difference in the number of notifications pre/post outbreak, or if there was a difference in age pre/post outbreak for each state. Does that help explain the "individual group level"?

Comment: missanita, can you amplify on precisely what you mean by "the individual group level?" Very often "individual" and "group" mean two different things. If you could go ahead an edit your question (the edit link is at the lower left) to clear that point up I might be able to offer you useful insights.

Comment: Hi Alexis, have provided more information, hopefully it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: am using *prtesti* with input from the proportion tables I created

Comment: Do you mean "column" (i.e. variable) rather than "row"? And what does "individual group level" mean? Do you simply mean "state level?" If so, just write "state level."

Comment: Sorry, yes I did mean column. But there are several groups in which the data can be categorised, so if you want me to call it "state level" the  cool, but it also could be categorised in regional level and private/public test labs or a range of other categories - basically I just want to be able to determine at each group level if there was a statistically significant change.